# Radio button is not clickable in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to iterate the radio buttons using ng-repeat. All the radio buttons are visible perfectly with first radio button checked, but when I try to select the other radio buttons, radio buttons are not clickable. can anybody please help me out what I am missing here..!!

```
 <div class="form-group form-radio" ng-repeat="n in [0,1]">
                          <div class="col-sm-12">
                             <div class="radio padding-bottom20">
                                <input class="form-input"  type="radio" id="rb4" name="optionsRadiosA" value="option4" checked="">
                                <label class="form-label" for="rb4">{{n}}</label>
                             </div>
                          </div>
                       </div>
```

Comment: ng-model is missing for radio buttons it could be `ng-model="radio[$index]"`

Comment: All your radio buttons have the same value (and id).

Comment: While inside a loop id of radio button should be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   <div class="form-group form-radio" ng-repeat="n in [0,1]">
                          <div class="col-sm-12">
                             <div class="radio padding-bottom20">
                                <input class="form-input"  type="radio" id="rb4_{{$index}}" name="optionsRadiosA"    ng-model="radioVal[$index]">
                                <label class="form-label" for="rb4_{{$index}}">{{n}}</label>
                             </div>
                          </div>
                       </div>
```

I have added ng-model="radioVal_{{$index}}" in each of input iteration, why because it's ng-model who will contain current ng-value of your radio buttons. Try it, and get back to me.

and Id's are dynamically generated now.

**Working Now!!!!!!**

Comment: this won't work ng-model never accepts interpolation

Comment: Thanks  @Rishi Prakash its working fine for me...!! But one small change is id value should be same as for value  id="rb4_{{n}}" and for="rb4_{{n}}"

Comment: made that change, check it. And If I have helped ,you can accept my answer(or an answer which have helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

corrected html

```
<div class="form-group form-radio" ng-repeat="n in [0,1]">
                          <div class="col-sm-12">
                             <div class="radio padding-bottom20">
                                <input class="form-input"  type="radio" id="rb4_{{n}}" name="optionsRadiosA" value="{{n}}" checked="">
                                <label class="form-label" for="rb4_{{n}}">{{n}}</label>
                             </div>
                          </div>
                       </div>
```

Comment: you just make it dynamic and it will work
 id="rb4_{{n}}" and for="rb4_{{n}}"

Answer (score 0):

You should have different ng-model for each radio element, you could do it by using `ng-model="radio[$index]"`

**Markup**

```
<div class="form-group form-radio" ng-repeat="n in [0,1]">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="radio padding-bottom20">
            <input class="form-input" type="radio" id="rb4-{{$index}}" name="optionsRadiosA" ng-value="option4" ng-model="radioVal">
            <label class="form-label" for="rb4">{{n}}</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't seem to understand how radio buttons work. All yur radio buttons have a different name, so they're not mutually exclusive. They also have the same id, which makes the html code invalid and the labels not functional.

Comment: @pankajparkar That's mistake, you need to keep Ids different but names must be same.

Comment: oh I missed id part let me fix it, mistakenly i did for name & it should be for id, I updated my answer @JBNizet Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the following issues:

1. The model must exist in parent scope. To do this, use ngInit to initialize an ngModel outside of your ngRepeat: `ng-init="selected = { number:0 }"`
2. All radio button controls must bind to the same ngModel. Add an ngModel to your input control, and bind it to the ngModel that you declared in parent scope:  `ng-model="selected.number"`
3. Display different values for each radio button: `value="{{n}}"`

NOTE: Remember, ngRepeat creates a child scope for each iteration.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app  ng-init="selected = { number:0 }">
  <div class="form-group form-radio" ng-repeat="n in [0,1]">
                          <div class="col-sm-12">
                             <div class="radio padding-bottom20">
                                <input class="form-input" ng-model="selected.number" type="radio" value="{{n}}">
                                <label class="form-label" for="rb4">{{n}}</label>
                             </div>
                          </div>
                       </div>
  {{ selected }}
</div>
```